# How many roots does a complex polynomial has?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

> Define $f(z)=z^4-4z^3+8z-2$. Find how many zeros (including multiplicity) the function has in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<3\}$.

I tried using Rouché's-theorem on $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<3\}$. The dominant factor is $z$, so $$|f(z)|\le|z+8z|=g(z)$$g(z) has only one root so $f(z)$ also has one root. for $1<|z|<3$$$|f(z)|<|z^4+8z|=h(z)$$ and $h(z)$ has three roots in this range (the ones for the equation $z^3=-8$) so I get it has four roots in this domain but when I solve it using MATLAB, I get that in $1<|z|<3$ there are two roots and not three. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g(z) = z^4-4 z^3$. Clearly if $|z|=3$ we have $g(z) \neq 0$.

If $|z| = 3$, then $|f(z)-g(z)| = |8 z-2| \le 26 < 27 = |z|^3 (4-3) \le |z|^3|z-4|  = |g(z)|$.

Hence $f,g$ have the same zeros in $|z|<3$.

Comment: so what was my mistake?

Comment: Why did you pick your particular $g$? Actually, I'm not exactly sure what you are doing in the question. For example, I would say that $z^4$ is the dominant factor.

Comment: because if $|z|<1$ then I switched $z^4$ in $z$ and removed the minuses. According to MATLAB, it has one root in $|z|<1$ so I think the mistake is with $h(z)$ but alas I can't find it.

Comment: Why are you dealing with $|z|<1$??? The question asks about $|z|<3$.

Comment: I devided the region into two subregions. I can do it, can't I?

Comment: I really don't follow what you are doing, you are making the problem much more complicated than necessary and I don't see the point of the split. Also, your first inequality is false, you have $f(-2) = 30, g(-2) = -18$.

Comment: Look at the 'symmetric version' in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem. Generally you are looking for some $g$ such that $|f(z)-g(z)| < |f(z)|+|g(z)| $ for $z$ on the boundary.